# what is the deference between deference "screen" and "lighter"?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

> lighter Where both shapes overlap the color is determined by adding
> color values. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing/Example)

[image]
[image]
[image]

> screen: The pixels are inverted, multiplied, and inverted again. A
> lighter picture is the result (opposite of multiply). [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing/Example)

[image]
[image]
[image]

the results are the same.

So how are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithms are not the same: [lighter](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#porterduffcompositingoperators_plus) & [screen](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#blendingscreen).

The results are not the same either:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const w = canvas.width = 500;
const h = canvas.height = 100;
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
// a vertical gradient black (top) to white (bottom)
const grad1 = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, 0, h );
grad1.addColorStop( 0, "black" );
grad1.addColorStop( 1, "white");
ctx.fillStyle = grad1;
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
// two horizontal rainbows
const grad2 = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, w/2, 0);
const d = 1/360;
for(let i = 0; i<360; i++ ) {
  grad2.addColorStop( i*d, `hsl(${ i }deg,50%,50%)` );
}
// first with "screen" mode on the left
ctx.fillStyle = grad2;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w/2, h );
// second with "lighter" mode on the right
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.translate( w/2, 0 );
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w/2, h );
```

```html
<canvas></canvas><br>
left: screen<br>
right: lighter<br>
```

But yes, with darker shades, the difference is less visible.